# how to create a multiple connection with advantage database server at same time?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to integrate alongside an existing application that uses ADS as its database.

When i connect my integration app using the code below it connects fine until i try and run the original application at the same time. It seems to only allow one connection, my application seems to hold the connection and block all others. Yet i can have multiple instances of the original application running conncurrently with no issue. Which leads me to believe that its the way in which i am trying to correct from my c# app. The error im getting when the original app is open and i then try to connect with my integration app is "The Advantage Data Dictionary cannot be opened. axServerConnect" .

> Error 7077: The Advantage Data Dictionary cannot be opened. axServerConnect

Anyone any suggestions? How to create a multiple connection at same time?

Python code:

```
conn = adsdb.connect(DataSource=str(dbpath[0]), ServerType='local', 
UserID = config.ADS_USERNAME, password=config.ADS_PASS)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10/index.html?dotnet_advantage_net_data_provider_and_connection_pooling.htm) in ADS documentations, you can use connection pooling by providing `pooling=True` to your client connection arguments.

I think using this approach, you will be able to open multiple connections at the same time.

**Edit**

After checking `adsdb` python script, I think it does not support connection pooling. You probably be able to set that connection pooling in your `C#` application.

Comment: Ok thanks, we are trying to check about connection pooling.